# How to add "hide already selected" feature to filter antd tags in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, antd

[image]

I want to implement a tag feature where it should filter based on the image given below on the antd table. I have used selectedItems state to get the tags from Select component but I am not able to filter based on selectedItems. How can I filter?

```
{
        title: 'Tags',
        dataIndex: 'tags',
        key: 'tags',
        filterDropdown: () => (
            <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
                <Select
                    mode="multiple"
                    showSearch={true}
                    placeholder="Select tags"
                    value={selectedItems}
                    onChange={setSelectedItems}
                    style={{ width: 200, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
                    options = {filteredItems.map((item)=> ({
                        value: item,
                        label: item,
                    }))}
                
                />
            </div>
        ),
        filterIcon: filtered => (
            <span style={{ color: filtered ? '#1677ff' : undefined }}>
                <FilterOutlined />
            </span>
        ),
        onFilter: (value, record) => record.tags.some(tag => selectedItems.includes(tag)),  
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    title: 'Tags',
    dataIndex: 'tags',
    key: 'tags',
    filterDropdown: () => (
        <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
            <Select
                mode="multiple"
                showSearch={true}
                placeholder="Select tags"
                value={selectedItems}
                onChange={setSelectedItems}
                style={{ width: 200, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
                options = {filteredItems.map((item)=> ({
                    value: item,
                    label: item,
                }))}
            
            />
        </div>
    ),
    filterIcon: filtered => (
        <span style={{ color: filtered ? '#1677ff' : undefined }}>
            <FilterOutlined />
        </span>
    ),
    filteredValue: selectedItems,
    onfilter: (value, record) => record.tags.includes(value),
},
```

filteredValue is a prop that takes in selectedItems (of type string[]).